# Find line equation if it passes through 2 points and has an angle with Oz

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Line goes through point $(1,0,0)$, on **z** axis cuts of a, $1/√5$ long, part and with that axis has an angle of $arccos(2/3)$

I need it in this form

[image]

Some questions I have about this:

can I find vector of direction(a,b,c), just by finding line segments of these 2 dots?

for (x0,y0,z0) can I use one of points that I already used in finding direction?

Comment: I would say, vector of direction $(a, b, c) = (1,0,0) - (0,0,1/\sqrt{5}) =(1,0,-1/\sqrt{5})$

Comment: It make sense, but when I plug it into angle equation I get an inequality

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood example. But I would say, the angle of arccos(2/3) does not work out. Perhaps advise someone else.

Comment: Most likely, there's a mistake in a problem. It's should be a simple line though 2 dots problem.